# Ubuntu 11.04 mini boots to black screen, alt-f2 restores monitor image.

Tags: video, display, ubuntu-minimal

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 mini CD, a command line only version of Ubuntu.  When the machine boots, I see all the bios screens, but when it boots in to Ubuntu the screen goes black.  The monitor light is green, but pressing keys.  The screen is black.

I tried pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f2</kbd> and the screen is restored.  I can see the normal Ubuntu cli login prompt.

What is <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f2</kbd> doing to bring video back and how can I have it boot up that way to begin with?

For reference, this is an `ibm eserver 8676-41X` machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alt+F2 changes your session to tty2
See here: http://wiki.debian.org/getty

Perhaps you're on Alt+F7 for some reason.. which is where is typically where your X session is.

Honestly, there is probably little reason to care if it's a cli only box.